# Android: Get already displayed activity on front, not by calling finish() on current activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have an activity A, which invokes Activity B And then upon clicking buttons It goes to Activity C and D.

In activity C and D there is a button called Back. And on click of back button, activity A should come on front with same data that was shown previously.

More Detail: When Activity A is first called it receives some bundles to fetch title and user name to show on the screen, remaining values on textviews on screen is fetched based on these two values.

Now the question is:

Is it possible to put Activity A on front with calling intent and without putting extras on it?? Is there any OS(2.1 onwards) supported mechanism  that shows me last bundle data if there is no new bundle passed??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the bundled stored in a local variable. When the activity goes in background, it is not always destroyed. So if you do a startActivity(A) it should bring activity A in front again, without restarting it. And if the bundle is empty that means Activity C or D has called this Activity. Also do check the [launch mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) for some details regarding the Activity's behavior.

Comment: Thanks for linking to the detail page... and that thing deserves an answer to be accepted